# OpenSSL DES-ECB key format - plaintext or hex

Tags: openssl, key, des

I've encrypted data with the command **openssl enc-des-ecb -e -K 12345678 -in fin.txt -out fout.enc**

I used http://des.online-domain-tools.com/ to test decryption, which works fine when 'key' is flagged as 'Hex' but not when it's flagged as 'Plaintext'.
The key as you can see above is just 8 digits.
I don't see any option in enc that specifies what format the key is in.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `-K` expects a hex encoded key (s. [`openssl enc`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html)) and expands a too short key with `0x00` values. The website does the same (if `hex` is chosen for the key). Therefore, both sites use the key `0x1234567800000000`. For `plaintext` and `12345678`, however, the keys differ on both sides and decryption fails. But actually off topic, since not programming related.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm coding this in C++ so from that point of view it's programming related. I encrypted a file using a hex key (using openssl) but the receiver requires the key to be in plaintext to decrypt? openssl does not give the option to encrypt using a plaintext key.

Comment: Maybe to put it another way: if a message is decrypted using a plaintext key, can the same hex equivalent key be used for the encryption? If not, would it suggest the openssl implementation is missing the functionality to encrypt using a plaintext key?

Comment: A cryptographic key is a byte sequence. You can convert a plaintext into a byte sequence by specifying an encoding. E.g. an ASCII encoding of the plaintext 12345678 results in the byte sequence 0x3132333435363738. So if you encrypt with OpenSSL with -K 3132333435363738 (DES assumed) you can decrypt with the string 12345678 as key if you apply ASCII encoding (since this results in 0x3132333435363738). I don't know if this answers your question, because I honestly don't understand exactly what the problem is.